# Pushing/Posting data to a generic url via a webhook

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, webhooks

Im trying to work out how to send data via a webhook.

If data changes in the database then i will send json data to a specific URL via a webhook. How can this be implemented using c# / azure function trigger apps?

Example; If surname changes in the database then i want an instant response to send the data surname change via json to the the customers URL alerting them of this change.

Am i correct in thinking if i have a timer trigger app to poll the changes to then ping the data via a webhook, would this work and how would i go about using a webhook. Doesnt seem to be many c# examples of this way of working?

Maybe i need to see a working example / sample code.

Not sure if this would be the right solution currently.

Thanks in advance of any answers / general guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently released [Azure SQL trigger for Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger) which will monitor a SQL table for changes and trigger an Azure Function when a row is created, updated, or deleted.  As far as sending the data to a webhook goes you'll need to issue a HTTP POST request using `HttpClient`, see these MS docs: [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests)

Comment: Thanks. Azure sql trigger looks good. However I don’t want it to be triggered every time a row is updated (if possible). Is there a way to trigger it by column only? I’ve had a good look and doesn’t look possible. Seems like I would need to add additional logic when triggered or to create a normal trigger at table level to then update certain columns in a different table acting as an audit. The sql azure trigger to monitor that audit table. Seems long way around it though.. thoughts? Tia

Comment: You mean you only want it to be triggered each time a certain column is updated on a row?  I think you'd have to code that behaviour yourself in the Function.